# how to get return value from python in php? it doesn't work

Tags: php, python, json

please help me... I have no idea.

This is part of my php code.

```
$result;
$resultD;
$arg= $ord." ".$time2_int;
$result=shell_exec('python3 decemberlist.py '.$arg);
$resultD=json_decode($result,true);
echo $resultD['song'];
```

And This is part of my python code.

```
import sys
import json

msg=''

def songName(a, b):
        global msg

        //

        return msg

ret=songName(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
rett={'song':ret}
print(rett)
print(json.dumps(rett, ensure_ascii=False))
```

php code print nothing. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

from [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), `shell_exec` is disabled when PHP is running in [safe mode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php).

but you can try this,

```
<?php
    $result;
    $resultD;
    $arg= $ord." ".$time2_int;


    $command = escapeshellcmd('python3 path/to/python_file/decemberlist.py '.$arg);
    $result= shell_exec($command);


    $resultD=json_decode($result,true);
    echo $resultD['song'];
 ?>
```